# Profiling web apps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, profiling

Is there a tool to profile web apps on the iPhone?

I'm looking for something like Google's Speed Tracer or the Network tab on Chrome's developer tools.  I'd like to see:

- which requests are made to the server
- what HTTP responses are given
- which items are pulled from cache, and
- a timeline of all the requests.

Ideally, this would profile web pages as well as web services requests made from within native apps.

Is there any tool to do this?  Does anyone have a good way to get at this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [weinre](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre) might be exactly what you want. It is a remote FireBug clone; you put one line into your HTML, run a server on your desktop, then work in a FireBug-like tool on your desktop; you can even run stuff from a console, to be executed on your web page that is being displayed on your iPhone.

Unfortunately, this is only for web pages (or web apps); I don't know how you could do it for the native apps.

**EDIT:** To see all traffic, you might consider a debugging HTTP proxy, such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Set up your iPhone at Settings -> WiFi -> [your access point] -> DHCP -> HTTP Proxy -> Manual, then sit back and let Fiddler count things for you.

Comment: Thanks! This seems very, very close, but weinre doesn't seem to (out of the box, at least) capture all HTTP requests from start to finish, only the XHR ones.  Is there a way to use it (or another tool) to capture *all* HTTP(s) requests, start to finish?

Comment: Updated my answer with another tool.